# VIM cmdline completion after '#' (hash key)

Tags: vim, completion

### SETUP

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Mar 31 2015 23:35:48)
Included patches: 1-488, 576
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org

`set wildmode?
  wildmode=list:longest,full`

- some plugins: i.e. UltiSnips

### Problem

when typing a `:call` command, where I'd like to invoke some routine of a plugin directely, *cmdline completion* (with <kbd>TAB</kbd> key, by default) stops after the `#`.

i.e.: I want to complete `:call UltiSnips#ListSnippets()`
where many other UltiSnips routines are available.

- When typing `:call ult` and press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, I get:
  `:call UltiSnips#` with a listing of all possible matches.

  1. When I press  <kbd>TAB</kbd> further, it toggles through all matches correctely
  2. BUT if I try to contiue typing the function name like `:call UltiSnips#List` and hit  <kbd>TAB</kbd>, it wont complete the funtion's name, but ANY completion, that is starting with `List` (what I typed after the `#`; `ListTemplateSuffixes(` in my case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed by recent Vim patch 7.4.516: *issue 253: completing function name with a # does not work*.

So, you just need to update your Vim (by compiling it yourself; or just wait until your distribution provides such upgrade).